dismiss ModalBottomSheetLayout without animation
I have ModalBottomsheetLayout
@Composable
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
fun ModalBottomSheetSample() {
    val state = rememberModalBottomSheetState(ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden)
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    ModalBottomSheetLayout(
        sheetState = state,
        sheetContent = {
            Text(text = "text")
        }
    }
}

and I want it to dismiss immediately without animation.
The reason I want to do it that when I close it I need to open a new one sequentially and I don't want it to look like multiple bottomsheets. I want it to look smooth like the content changes within the same bottomsheet or at least make it look as smooth as possible.
Is there a way to do that?

"I want it to look smooth like the content changes within the same bottomsheet or at least make it look as smooth as possible." - that sounds like you want to swap out your sheetContent with new content. Is there a reason you're trying to make it two separate bottom sheets if you want it to act like the same bottom sheet?

@ianhanniballake I wish I could swap content. We have 2 bottomsheet,  1 of them is compose , and 2nd one is legacy XML. And we want to open 2nd bottomshhet when user finishes interactions with 1st bottomsheet and we want it to look seemless. Also, 2nd bottomsheet has a beast fragment which  we are not comfortable using inside compose AndroidBinding b/c of stability issues and other risks.

I would suggest you append XML directly in your composeUI without changing logic and XML. In this case, 1 combined sheet will be there without a lot of effort, and in the future, you may change based on the need.

@MuhammadAmmar I explained why I can't do that in my previous comment

you mean it's lagging. when merging that legacy in compose?

I could simply hide the BottomSheetLayout immediately by wrapping it into an if block:
var showBottomSheet by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
//...

if(showBottomSheet) {
    ModalBottomSheetLayout(
        sheetState = state,
        sheetContent = {
            Text(text = "text")
        }
    }
}

Then, to show or hide the BottomSheetLayout, try the following code:
// show BottomSheet
showBottomSheet = true
state.show()

// hide BottomSheet
showBottomSheet = false    
state.hide()

